# Pylint cannot handle abstract subclasses of abstract base classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint, abc

I have a concrete class `MyConcreteClass` which subclasses an *abstract*
class `MyABC2`, which, in turn, subclasses another *abstract* class `MyABC1`:

```
import abc

class MyABC1 (object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_method (self):
        raise NotImplementedError("MyABC1.my_abstract_method")

class MyABC2 (MyABC1):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

class MyConcreteClass (MyABC2):
    def my_abstract_method (self):
        print "MyConcreteClass.my_abstract_method"
```

`pylint` does not like that I do not define `my_abstract_method` in `MyABC2`:

```
/usr/local/bin/epylint abctest.py
************* Module abctest
 abctest.py:9: warning (W0223, abstract-method, MyABC2) Method 'my_abstract_method' is abstract in class 'MyABC1' but is not overridden
```

Is this a known bug?
Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pylint's notion of when a class is intended to be abstract is a bit limited. Basically, it can't tell that you intended the `MyABC2` class to be an abstract class. Its logic assumes that if you don't declare any methods in the class that are decorated with `@abstractmethod` (or raise `NotImplementedError`), you intended the class to be concrete. In such a situation, failing to override the inherited abstract methods would be an error.

Declaring the metaclass in `MyABC2` doesn't help. In fact, that declaration is completely redundant, since a subclass inherits its metaclass from its parent class.

So that's the reason for the incorrect warning. Now the question is what to do about it. Ideally, pylint would be a bit more sophisticated and handle this situation better, but fixing the issue would be difficult. I don't really know how it can tell the difference between a mid-level abstract class that doesn't add any new abstract methods and a incorrectly implemented concrete class.

So probably the only option is to disable the warning for that class. Try adding the following comment to your code just above the class declaration: `# pylint: disable=W0223`. (It might also work if you put the comment inside the class, I'm not sure.)

Comment: It would be nice if we could just put a no-op decorator like `@abstractclass` as signal to linters.